# How to configure symfony2/3 to handle different domains serving different views?

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to configure symfony2/3 to handle more than 1 domain with different views?

For example I have site1.com and site2.com, I would create a site1 and site2 folders inside app/Resources/views and serve a different set of templates depending on the domain.

Models and controllers should be in common so site1.com/mypage and site2.com/mypage should serve the same content with different layout.

Any suggestion or best practice related to it is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I expect the following should work. You'll want to register a kernel request listener that uses the Twig loader service (responsible for locating the templates) and registers a path based on the request's hostname.

Create a request listener:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RegisterTwigPathSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $loader;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Loader_Filesystem $loader)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'registerTwigPath'
        ];
    }

    public function registerTwigPath(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $host = $event->getRequest()->getHost();
        $path = '...'; // determine path based on hostname
        $this->loader->addPath($path, 'Theme'); // the second argument is a namespace for templates located under this folder and can be chosen
    }
}
```

Register the event listener:

```
services:
    register_twig_path_listener:
        class: RegisterTwigPathSubscriber
        arguments: ["@twig.loader"]
        tags: [{ name: kernel.event_subscriber }]
```

Now to reference the template:

```
return $this->render('@Theme/path/to/actual/template.html.twig');
```

Comment: seems it is partialy working, I only get an error saying The "my_folder" directory does not exist, but I actually created the folder inside app/Resources/views. I also made a test creating the same directory inside src/AppBundle/resources/views but no luck, can you help me with that? thanks.

Comment: Can you give the specific error message and stack trace?

Comment: it is too long but the first lines are

Twig_Error_Loader in Filesystem.php line 94:
The "my_folder" directory does not exist.
in Filesystem.php line 94

Comment: Well the most logical explanation is that the path you are registering does not exist.

Comment: for now I just put something like if($host == 'mysite.com') $path = 'my_folder': where should I put my_folder? in app/Resources/views? or in AppBundle? or should I have to append $path to some constant? 'cause I am just passing to addpath() the folder name not a full path.

Comment: well I added this and it works

$path = __DIR__.'/../../../app/Resources/views/'.$path;

I know it is not the finest solution but I will move on for now. thanks for your help.

Comment: So what happens if the condition is false? An empty $path is added?

Comment: in theory yes, but ideally I should map the folders only for the domains allowed in httpd.conf.

Comment: Well you should only register a path if it exists, so you might need to change the code in the listener a bit to fit your specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

Check for the host in your controller :

```
namespace Acme\FooBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DemoController
{
    public function showAction(Request $request)
    {
        switch($request->getHost())
        {
            case 'site1.com':
                return $this->render('site1/show.html.twig');
            break;
            case 'site2.com':
                return $this->render('site2/show.html.twig');
            break;
            default:
                return $this->render('default/show.html.twig');
        }        
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT : Something more generic**

Create a onKernelRequest listener :

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class DomainRequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $host = explode('.',$request->getHost());

        $request->request->attributes->set('_domain',$host[0]);
    }
}
```

Add this listener in services.yml :

```
    app.listener.domain_request:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\DomainRequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest}
```

Then you can use the '_domain' routing parameter in all your controllers :

```
return $this->render($request->attributes->get('_domain').'/show.html.twig');
```

Comment: I can't do this in all the controllers, I need something more generic...

Comment: `$request->get('_domain')` this code is actually dangerous, as this way the parameter can be provided in for example the query string.

Comment: If it is provided in the query string, it will be overwritten in the listener. No ?

Comment: That sounds logical, but is not enforced in the code, so it's a dangerous road. Better would be using the request attributes: $request->attributes->set() and $request->attributes->get()